# Avoid calling both HashMap::get() and HashMap::get_mut() when borrowing 'self'

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I'm learning rust and I find myself writing lots and lots of code that disappoints the borrow checker. I've recently ran into this quirk that I can't figure out a way around.

To set the scene: I would like to (1) fetch a struct from a HashMap, (2) compute some metadata about the fetched struct, then (3) modify the fetched struct. Simple! See a simplified example below:

```
struct Entity {
    pub metadata: i64
}
struct Engine {
    pub entities: HashMap<i32, Box<Entity>>
}
impl Engine {
    fn immutable_calculate_metadata(&self, new_metadata: i64) -> i64 {
        // Compute a bunch of stuff that requires reading "self"
        42 + new_metadata
    }
    pub fn add_entity(&mut self, key: i32, metadata: i64) {
        self.entities.insert(key, Box::new(Entity{metadata}));
        let neighbor_key = &(key - 1);
        if let Some(neighbor) = self.entities.get_mut(neighbor_key) {
            let metadata = self.immutable_calculate_metadata(metadata);
            // I *want* to write this line, but it breaks:
            // neighbor.metadata = metadata;
            // So I have to re-fetch the same key.
            self.entities.get_mut(neighbor_key).unwrap().metadata = metadata;
        }
    }
}
```

(rust playground: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=cf53e4af2d41add3765578e619c75e5e )

I don't know how I can remove the redundant fetch in the
`self.entities.get_mut(neighbor_key).unwrap().metadata = metadata;` line. Any help here would be greatly appreciated. Ideally someone who knows what they're doing (read: you) could enumerate the options I have here to avoid this.

Of course, if I try to do this intuitively (see the commented out line `// neighbor.metadata = metadata;`) I get the following error:

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `*self` as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable
   |
18 |         if let Some(neighbor) = self.entities.get_mut(neighbor_key) {
   |                                 ----------------------------------- mutable borrow occurs here
19 |             let metadata = self.immutable_calculate_metadata(metadata);
   |                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ immutable borrow occurs here
20 |             // I *want* to write this line, but it breaks:
21 |             neighbor.metadata = metadata;
   |             ---------------------------- mutable borrow later used here
```

I don't exactly understand why `self.entities.get_mut(neighbor_key)` is considered a "mutable borrow of `*self`". It seems to me we're borrowing an `Entity` or a `HashMap` but that's not the focus of this question.

Comment: What fields do you need to access in `immutable_calculate_metadata()`? Does it need to access `entities`?

Comment: See [update struct using a value from the struct itself gives: "cannot borrow `*self` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67027724/7884305), [&mut getter in another method causes "cannot borrow as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72026001/7884305) and [dozens of other posts](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Brust%5D+cannot+borrow+self+as+mutable+because+it+is+also+borrowed+as+immutable)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [&mut getter in another method causes "cannot borrow as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72026001/mut-getter-in-another-method-causes-cannot-borrow-as-immutable-because-it-is-a)

Comment: Seeing your actual code would be helpful as the answer will depend on what `immutable_calculate_metadata` _actually_ does. Your contrived example has several very simple solutions that your actual code likely doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't exactly understand why self.entities.get_mut(neighbor_key) is considered a "mutable borrow of *self".

Since `entities` is a part of `self`, and any `HashMap` entry is a part of the hash map, mutating even a single entry in `entities` counts as mutating `self`.

Due to how Rust's borrow checker works (and like the error message you received suggests), you won't be allowed to borrow `self` as immutable while also borrowing it as mutable. The reason for this constraint is exactly due to the fact that mutating a single entry means mutation to the whole `self`, and therefore violating the immutability contract with `immutable_calculate_metadata`.

> ... enumerate the options I have here to avoid this.

RECOMMENDED (probably what you want):

1. Consider converting `immutable_calculate_metadata` into an associated function (remove `&self` from signature).
   Does it actually need `&self`, or perhaps it would be better to only give it (by value) the specific parameters it needs from the `Engine` struct? More context about your actual use case would be helpful here.

```rust
fn immutable_calculate_metadata(new_metadata: i64) -> i64 {
    // Doesn't require reading "self" anymore
    42 + new_metadata
}
pub fn add_entity(&mut self, key: i32, metadata: i64) {
    self.entities.insert(key, Box::new(Entity { metadata }));
    let neighbor_key = &(key - 1);
    if let Some(neighbor) = self.entities.get_mut(neighbor_key) {
        let metadata = Engine::immutable_calculate_metadata(metadata);
        // No breakage
        neighbor.metadata = metadata;
    }
}
```

LESS RECOMMENDED (it would solve your problem, but probably not in the way you intended)

2. Leave almost everything as it is, with the small difference of calculating the metadata *before* the `if let` scope. Of course this solution would have performance implications in the case of large and heavy calculations, but in some cases it might actually be more performant then re-fetching the key twice.

```rust
fn immutable_calculate_metadata(&self, new_metadata: i64) -> i64 {
    // Compute a bunch of stuff that requires reading "self"
    42 + new_metadata
}
pub fn add_entity(&mut self, key: i32, metadata: i64) {
    self.entities.insert(key, Box::new(Entity { metadata }));
    let neighbor_key = &(key - 1);
    let metadata = self.immutable_calculate_metadata(metadata);
    if let Some(neighbor) = self.entities.get_mut(neighbor_key) {
        // No breakage
        neighbor.metadata = metadata;
    }
}
```

NOT RECOMMENDED (this one is NOT a good solution, as it just blindly satisfies the borrow checker, disregarding the implications. I'm mentioning it only for the sake of completeness)

3. Clone the entire `entities` HashMap. The borrow checker will be satisfied, but this will most likely heavily affect performance.

```rust
fn immutable_calculate_metadata(&self, new_metadata: i64) -> i64 {
    // Compute a bunch of stuff that requires reading "self"
    42 + new_metadata
}
pub fn add_entity(&mut self, key: i32, metadata: i64) {
    self.entities.insert(key, Box::new(Entity { metadata }));
    let neighbor_key = &(key - 1);
    let mut entities = self.entities.to_owned();
    if let Some(neighbor) = entities.get_mut(neighbor_key) {
        let metadata = self.immutable_calculate_metadata(metadata);
        // No breakage
        neighbor.metadata = metadata;
    }
    self.entities = entities;
}
```

Comment: Option 4: If `immutable_calculate_metadata` doesn't need access to `self.entities` one could "cheat" and make `self.entities` a `RefCell<HashMap<_, _>>`, then take `&self` instead of `&mut self`.